# To add/remove table columns with drop down check-boxes (check list) using jquery

Tags: jquery, checkbox

I want to edit a table - Add/Remove its columns with drop-down check boxes. Can anyone tell me how? I could do it with ordinary checkbox, but could not find out how by drop-down checkbox. This is my code:

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/themlas/m8X7j/)

```
<script>
$("button").click(function() {
    $("p").toggle();
     var btnID = $(this).attr('id');

    var coresDiv = $('div#' + btnID);

    coresDiv.toggle();
});

$("#selector").click(function() {
    $("#main").toggle();
    $("p").toggle();
});
</script>
```

When check box is ticked, corresponding column is to be displayed. When unchecked column is to be removed.

Can you give me full HTML code? When I put the fiddle to notepad and saved as HTML it does not work. Some full code would be really helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$("input[type='checkbox']").change(function() {
    var val = $(this).val();    
    $("#mytable tr:first").find("th:eq("+val+")").toggle();
    $("#mytable tr").each(function(){
        $(this).find("td:eq("+val+")").toggle();
    });
    if($("#mytable tr:first").find("th:visible").length > 0){
        $("#mytable").removeClass("noborder");
    }
    else{
        $("#mytable").addClass("noborder");
    }
});
```

[**Fiddle here.**](http://jsfiddle.net/m8X7j/3/)

Comment: a new problem. copy-paste the code to notepad and save as .html, does not display drop-down list. What could be the problem?

Answer (score 1):

You can add a `data-*` attribute to the checkbox indicating which columnd is depended on that as given below

```
<input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Bike" data-column="1" />Index
```

then

```
$('input[type="checkbox"]').click(function () {
    $('#mytable tr > :nth-child(' + $(this).data('column') + ')').toggle(!this.checked)
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/kM6ma/)

Comment: The idea is correct. But the reverse is happening. when box unchecked-column added. When checked column is removed. I want the reverse. When unchecked-column is removed. Thanks